# Audio/Video Chatting bundle name or how to developed functionality in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, video-streaming, chat, audio-streaming

I need to developed Audio/Video conversion functionality in symfony2, If you know any bundle provide Audio/Video conversion functionality or is this possible using symfony2 API or any other ways..?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best tool to do that is FFMPEG, there is a simple wraper developed here: https://github.com/pulse00/ffmpeg-bundle